# PHP. How to check if a e-mail domain exists?

Tags: php, validation, email, dns

I'd like to know how can I check if I have a valid e-mail, including the domain.

For example,

e-mails like:

`email1@gmail.com`, `email2@hotmail.com` should return true,

but e-mails like:

`email3@gmal.com`, `email4@hotmai.com` should return false.

How can we do this?

I can check if a e-mail is a valid one with `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, but this don't guarantee that we can send the e-mail (email3@gmal.com is a example). How can we guarantee that we have a valid domain?

Comment: `nslookup`, but that offers you no guarantee that mail is deliverable.  Cyber squatters have most domains similar to other domains.

Comment: you could explode `@` and then ping the domain.

Comment: Why couldn't `email4@hotmai.com` be a valid email address?   Send a verification email if you want to see if an email address is valid.

Comment: oh and `hotmai` is valid

Comment: you could also do a mx loopup http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3ahotmail.com&run=toolpage

Comment: Well I received timeout when pinging homai.com (ping hotmai.com) but php > echo gethostbyname('hotmai.com');
65.55.39.12 ˆˆ

Answer (score 3):

You could **create a whitelist** of acceptable domains **but that would no doubt leave out many valid services**.

You could try to **connect to the domain** on the appropriate port after doing an MX dig **but what if the service is down** for an hour for maintenance?

The **best way** to determine if an email is valid **is by sending a verification code** and have the user click on/enter the code after receiving the email.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **CURL** to check if domain exist, this option is very simple but works very well. Is fast to implement.

Check this response for well tested solution:
 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12547629/1146492

To get domain email you can use something like this:

```
<?php
function getDomainFromEmail($email)
{
// Get the data after the @ sign
$domain = substr(strrchr($email, "@"), 1);

return $domain;
}

// Example

$email = 'the_username_here@yahoo.com';

$domain = getDomainFromEmail($email);

echo $domain; // yahoo.com
?>
```

And than use CURL for fast check.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to attempt to connect to the domain and see if it's successful or not:

```
if(fopen("http://$domain"))
{
    echo "success, valid domain";
} else {
    echo "failure, not valid domain";
}
```

Where `$domain` is the portion of the email address following the `@` symbol. (This can be obtained using regular expressions).

Comment: Thx, quinxorin. Why about filter_var(gethostbyname('gmal.com'), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP); Is this better or not? Why? Do you have some answer to this?

Comment: Whether or not there is an HTTP server running on the domain has nothing to do with whether or not it is valid for email.

Comment: That's actually a better answer, as it would be considerably faster.

Comment: Hello guys i am about to use this code to check emails .... is it good or should i search for another function ?? i want a faster and reliable function